# Pl Sql Environment Setup for Windows 7 for learning purposes

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Iam familiar with Sql Server,but now i need to learn Pl/Sql .So,please suggest me what needs to be installed in my laptop and also sample database for running sample programs in Pl/Sql.
I dont have any server configuration.
Sql developer or Sql Plus what is better in my case.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) express should do you nicely...